# how to make labels and button appear only when mouse is over a div in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have a div with few labels in. the div has a circle shape, but when the mouse is over. it transforms to a square where you see some information (basically labels and buttons) the codes are this:

```
 <div id="UserIconCircle">
                <i class="fa fa-user-md fa-2x" id="UserIconTop"></i>

             <asp:Label ID="FirstName" runat="server" Text="Dikush"></asp:Label>
             <asp:Label ID="LastName" runat="server" Text="Dikushi"></asp:Label>

             <asp:Label ID="UnderName" runat="server" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
             <asp:Label ID="UnderLastName" runat="server" Text="Last Name"></asp:Label>
 </div>
```

and the css code is this:

```
#UserIconCircle {
    position: absolute;
 
    top: 120px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;

    border: 4px solid  #373e4a;
    border-radius: 50px;

    -webkit-transition-property: width, height; /* Safari */
    -webkit-transition-duration: 3s; /* Safari */
    transition-property: width, height;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;

    z-index: 4;
}
    #UserIconCircle:hover {
        width: 240px;
        height: 260px;
        background-color: #373e4a;
        border-radius:4px;
        border-top-left-radius: 20px;
        z-index: 4;
    }
```

when the mouse is over it looks like this:

[image: img1]

and when is not it looks like this:

[image: img2]

the labels still stay visible when the mouse is not over div..

I tried to make a c# code by adding `runnat="server"` at the div and trying to put `label.visible=false` but couldnt figure out how to make mouseover and call it in page.aspx.cs.

any suggestion? is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden;` to the `#UserIconCircle` style.

Comment: @VDWWD wow, much thanks man, I was working a lot to find a way to make this happen. was testing a lot. really easy with this..

can you please post this as an answer so I can approve it as the solution? the guy who gave java code didnt help me much

Comment: I've made it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `overflow: hidden;` to the `#UserIconCircle` style, the content will not be visible.
See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Handle this on the Client side, get Javascript to make the label appear/disappear.

There are few ways to achieve this.

1. use Javascript. so in your .aspx file

   ```
   <div id="UserIconCircle">
       <script>
         function makeMeVisible()
         {
           document.getElementById("FirstName").visible = false;
         }
       </script>
       <i class="fa fa-user-md fa-2x" id="UserIconTop"></i>
       <asp:Label ID="FirstName" runat="server" Text="Dikush" onmouseover="makeMeVisible();"></asp:Label>
       <asp:Label ID="LastName" runat="server" Text="Dikushi"></asp:Label>
   </div>
   ```
2. in your server side code, you can use [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx) to regisiter client scripts with the Page object

Hope this helps